# Google Charts Get maximum scale

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I'm trying to make an all positive bubble chart have quadrants by drawing the quadrants using the baseline property like so:

```
var dataT = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(.....);
var options = {
    hAxis: {title: 'h axis',baseline:100},
    vAxis: {title: 'v axis',baseline:20},
    ...}
var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(...);
chart.draw(dataT,options);
```

Except the graph will keep changing depending on the query so the baselines will not be the same for all the graphs. I would like to be able to get the max axis value and divide it by 2 to set the baselines right in the middle of each axis.

Example:

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {title: 'h axis',baseline:max_h_axis/2},
    vAxis: {title: 'v axis',baseline:max_v_axis/2},
    ...
```

Is there any way of knowing the max axis values of the graph before drawing the graph?

Comment: Yes, loop through the `dataT` collection to find the largest value.

Answer (score 1):

the [`getColumnRange`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getColumnRange) method works for this...

> Returns the minimal and maximal values of values in a specified column. The returned object has properties min and max. If the range has no values, min and max will contain null.

you can also use this information to produce your own axis tick marks.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Y'],
      [8,   120],
      [4,   155],
      [11,  140],
      [4,   205],
      [3,    35],
      [6,    78]
    ]);

    var ticksX = [];
    var ticksY = [];
    var numberOfTicks = 10;

    var rangeX = data.getColumnRange(0);
    var rangeY = data.getColumnRange(1);

    var stepX = Math.ceil((rangeX.max - rangeX.min) / numberOfTicks);
    for (var i = rangeX.min - stepX; i <= rangeX.max + stepX; i = i + stepX) {
      ticksX.push(i);
    }

    var stepY = Math.ceil((rangeY.max - rangeY.min) / numberOfTicks);
    for (var i = rangeY.min - stepY; i <= rangeY.max + stepY; i = i + stepY) {
      ticksY.push(i);
    }

    var baseX = Math.ceil((rangeX.max - rangeX.min) / 2) + rangeX.min;
    var baseY = Math.ceil((rangeY.max - rangeY.min) / 2) + rangeY.min;

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        title: 'h axis',
        baseline: baseX,
        ticks: ticksX
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'v axis',
        baseline: baseY,
        ticks: ticksY
      },
      legend: 'none',
      height: 600,
      width: 600
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I had this in mind too but I would have to round up the max numbers so I could get it exactly in the middle since the axis always goes past the max numbers. Since the axis scale also differs in the different graphs, the route I'm going to have to go to is with a lot of if statements to try to guess the scale to round the max up to.

Comment: rather than _try to guess the scale_ -- provide your own axis tick marks -- see changed answer above...