# On Google bar charts, I am unable to remove columns which do not have data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, google-barchart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day',{ role: 'annotation' }],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8],
        ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
        ['Eat', 0,0],
        ['TV', 4,4],
        ['Gym', 0,0],
        ['Sleep', 8,8]
    ]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
    var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':2000, 'height': window.innerHeight};

    // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the page is loading, it displays every column’s data (whether it has data or not). I need to shorten: I don’t want to display columns which do not have data. I need to remove the column whose value is 0 5. I need to display the columns which do have data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a data view to draw the chart.

after creating the data view, we exclude the rows with zero values.

we do this by using the `getFilteredRows` method to find the rows not equal to zero.

then provide the return value to the `setRows` method.

see following working snippet...

```js
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day',{ role: 'annotation' }],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8],
    ['VehicleNumbering', 8,8],
    ['Eat', 0,0],
    ['TV', 4,4],
    ['Gym', 0,0],
    ['Sleep', 8,8]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 1,
    test: function (value) {
      return (value !== 0);
    }
  }]));

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':2000, 'height': window.innerHeight};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Comment: var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 1,
    test: function (value) {
      return (value !== 0);
    }
  }]));

Comment: same thing is i am using on 2 more charts but filter is applying on only one chart

Comment: make sure you draw the chart using the data view, not the data table...

Comment: var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

Comment: using same thing in every where

Comment: here? --> `chart.draw(view, options);` <-- use `view`

Comment: Thank u whitehat. its woking now

Comment: i have small doubt, in bar chart some time showing values in y axis like(range from 0,5,10), some times displaying nothing. is there any way to show permanentily

Comment: you can use option `vAxis.ticks` to display exactly what you want -- e.g. -- `vAxis: {ticks: [0, 5, 10]}`

Comment: i dont want to use those values,it should display automatically based on data

Comment: if i have data 1 to 50 based on that data it should apper

Comment: don't have to hard code, you can build the ticks dynamically, based on the data. you can use data table method [`getColumnRange`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getColumnRange) to determine the min & max values. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350811/5090771) is an example...

Comment: is it possible to display google chart title at center . instead of left i need at center WiteHat

Comment: no config option for that, you would have to move it manually on the chart's ready event, by changing the `"x"` attribute of the `<text>` element...